# Shell script: strange behavior with awk

Tags: shell

That's an shell script snippet:

```
KVS_VARIABLES=$(awk -F= '!($1 && $2 && NF==2) { print "File failed validation on line " NR | "cat 1>&2"; next } { print $1, $2 }' $ENV_FILE_LOCATION)
echo ${KVS_VARIABLES}

for kv in ${KVS_VARIABLES}
do
  echo $kv
  key=$(echo $kv | awk -FS=" " '{print $1}')
  value=$(echo $kv | awk -FS=" " '{print $2}')

  echo "key: $key | value: $value"
done
```

I expect an output like:

```
key: VAR1 | value: VAL1
...
```

However, I'm getting that:

```
VAR1 VAL1 VAR2 VAL2 VAR3 VAL3
VAR1
key: VAR1 | value: 
VAL1
key: VAL1 | value: 
VAR2
key: VAR2 | value: 
VAL2
key: VAL2 | value: 
VAR3
key: VAR3 | value: 
VAL3
key: VAL3 | value:
```

**EDIT**

File content is:

```
VAR1=VAL1
VAR2=VAL2
VAR3=VAL3
```

Comment: Please update your question with the input file you want to parse.

Comment: I've added the content of file on post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this awk script:

```
$ awk -F= -v OFS=' | ' '{$1="key: "$1;$2="value: "$2}1' file
key: VAR1 | value: VAL1
key: VAR2 | value: VAL2
key: VAR3 | value: VAL3
```

The input and output field separators are set to `=` and `|`values. The only awk statement is adding the string before keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with awk.

```
KVS_VARIABLES="VAR1 VAL1
VAR2 VAL2
VAR3 VAL3"
```

Now with a `for kv in ${KVS_VARIABLES}` you just iterate over the words (single words, not lines). The newlines gets ignored, because the variable is not escaped.
Now you want to iterate over lines or read two variables at a time and print them in a fancy fashion.

You can read lines (probably this is what you want):

```
while read -r key value; do
   echo "key: $key | value: $value"
done <<<"$KVS_VARIABLES"
```

If you don't have bash>4 with [here strings](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html), you can try [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
while read -r key value; do
   echo "key: $key | value: $value"
done < <(echo "$KVS_VARIABLES")
```

or a good old' pipe:

```
echo "$KVS_VARIABLES" | while read -r key value; do
   echo "key: $key | value: $value"
done
```

You can do iterate over two arguments at a time:

```
first=""
for kv in ${KVS_VARIABLES}; do
        if [ -z "$first" ]; then
                first="$kv"
        else
                echo "key: $first | value $kv"
                first=""
        fi
done
```

For a test, do in your console `for kv in ${KVS_VARIABLES}; do echo kv=$kv; done` and observe the output.

Comment: I've a systax problem on `done <<<"$KVS_VARIABLES"`: `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`